# Flask: URL_For for Javascript with Blueprints

Tags: javascript, python, flask, autocomplete

This is probably a stupid question related to Flask/Javascript, but I'm not able to make it work.

I have an autocomplete feature defined in Javascript. The idea is that once there are at least 3 characters, it goes to the database to find the different results and show the autocompleted values. It tries to go to Python, which queries the database and sends back the results.

For this approach:

- There is a script that is called when something is typed.(3 words)
- There is code in Python to go to the DB

The question is how to connect the script with Python and return the results. I'm able to make it work with a basic Flask application, but when there are blueprints involved, I don't know which url should be passed to make it work.

I guess the problem is on the **url_for** address, but I am not able to make it work with several options.

```
app/
-- __init.py__
-- base/
-- -- **static/ (contains the autocomplete function - Javascript - )**
-- -- templates/
-- -- __init.py__
-- -- **routes.py (contains /autocomplete)**
-- auxiliar/
-- -- static/
-- -- templates/
-- -- __init.py__
-- -- routes.py (I'm on these templates. The script is also called here, but nothing happens)
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("input[id^='asset']").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("{{url_for('autocomplete')}}", {
                q: request.term, 
            }, function (data) {
                response(data.matching_results.slice(0, 10)); 
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item.value); 
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {

            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

**Python**

```
@blueprint.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    search = request.args.get('q')

    results = []
    my_regex = re.compile("" + re.escape(search), re.IGNORECASE)

    query = list(security_db.find({"$or": [{"ticker": my_regex}, {"name": my_regex}, {"isin": my_regex}]}))

    for mv in query:
        ticker = mv['ticker'] if 'ticker' in mv else ''
        name = mv['name'] if 'name' in mv else ''
        isin = mv['isin'] if 'isin' in mv else ''
        results.append(ticker + " - " + name + " - " + isin)

    return jsonify(matching_results=results)
```

Thanks,
Kat

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the general category of fetching data with a function and sticking it in a web page somewhere (e.g. for dynamically modified dropdowns), which seems like it ought to be pretty simple, but because this is Flask, we have the function in Python, the html generated via Jinja and JavaScript providing reactivity, which can get a bit confusing.

Might be easiest to start on the JavaScript side of the house - let's assume a page with a dropdown list of modules which will then control what should be included in a dropdown list of functions.   When you change a field called `form_module`, we want to run the 'list update' function and update another field called `form_somefunction`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#form_module').change(function(){

        $.getJSON('/someblueprint/_update_func_dropdown', {
          selected_module: $('#form_module').val()

        }).done(function(data) {
              $('#form_somefunction').html(data.html_string_selected);
         })
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Notes:

- the function we're using to retrieve stuff from the database is called `_update_func_dropdown`, and it's using a blueprint with a root of `someblueprint`, so our reference to it is `'/someblueprint/_update_func_dropdown'` (we can't use url_for because this is JavaScript, but the function needs someblueprint for its route (see below))
- the Javascript is going to stick dynamically generated html into designated spot on the page
- I'm using jquery 3.3.1 here - note that getJSON is not in the .slim version of jquery
- Flask does not seem terribly concerned if your JavaScript fails - troubleshooting this can be a bit tricky - your browser's console can be useful to find problems

Next, the Python function in Flask

```
@some_blueprint.route('/_update_func_dropdown')
def _update_func_dropdown():
    """Update the function dropdown, based on the selected module (using request.args here)

    Returns:
        json: jsonified html to stick in page
    """
    # note that selected_module is set by Javascript
    # the value of the first dropdown (selected by the user)
    selected_module = request.args.get('selected_module', type=str)
    # get values for the second dropdown
    updated_values = get_modfunc_dropdown_values()[selected_module]
    # create the values in the dropdown as html string
    html_string_selected = ''
    for entry in updated_values:
        # Build out an option list
        html_string_selected += '<option value="{}">{}</option>'.format(entry, entry)

    return jsonify(html_string_selected=html_string_selected)
```

Notes:

- the `get_modfunc_dropdown_values()` is just another Python function that hits the Mongo database and returns a dict, keyed on the module name, so when we apply the selected module to that dict, we get back the list we want for our dropdown
- the `selected_module` argument was passed in by JavaScript with this line `$.getJSON('/someblueprint/_update_func_dropdown', {selected_module: $('#form_module').val()`
- the blueprint is called some_blueprint, and its url_prefix is someblueprint (the url_prefix is the thing we needed to use in the JavaScript
- in this case the value and its label (for the dropdown) are the same, but obviously you could construct this list anyway you want
- since our JavaScript is going to stick html into a spot on our page, we need to provide a properly formed bit of html that will work - to figure out what that should look like, we go to our template

Finally, let's open door number three and see what to do in Jinja

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="form_somefunction" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Function</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select class="form-control" id="form_somefunction" name="form_somefunction">
        {% for f in function_list %}
           <option value="{{ f }}">{{ f }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

- to populate the lists initially, you get the data in the route's function using the `get_modfunc_dropdown_values()` function we used to get the updated values, and pass the initial list in with render_template (e.g. `render_template('somemodfuncpage.html', function_list=default_function_list, form=someForm)` - the JavaScript is essentially just rewriting that list
- if you had passed in an existing variable too (e.g. because you were editing an existing record) you would just add a line `<option selected="selected">{{ passedinobject.SomeFunction }}</option>` after the endfor line

To me, the compelling thing about Flask is that I do all of my non-web app work in Python, so Flask makes it easy to re-use code and skills.  However, to make any kind of reactive page, you inevitably end up writing some JavaScript, so it's a good idea to build up a set of techniques and functions to make this easier.   There are likely better, more modern techniques than what I've outlined above, but this works.